# How to return ceiling of a number without using cmath

Tags: c++

How can I get the floor of two inputs of type double without using cmath:
this is what it works if the first input is negative but will not work for a positive integer not sure where its going wrong?? any insight is appreciated.. thank you

```
 int main()
{
 floors=floor(n1);
 cout<< " The floor of value 1 is " <<floors<<endl;
 floors=floor(n2);
 cout<<" The floor of value 2 is " <<floors<<endl;


long floor(long f)
{
  if( (f+ 0.5) >= (int(f)-1) )
  return int (f)-1;
  else 
  return int (f);
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking using static_cast<int> is much better than using the old c style casting syntax.

Comment: I like how your floor function takes integral types and is thus by definition useless.  Or would that be "by declaration" useless.

Comment: yes.. it is my weakness in programming is the math

Comment: please explain.. I am a novice in programming so i do not understand most of your comments... there is more to the code as this code has more functions to it thus...n1, n2

Comment: If you're writing a homebrew floor / ceiling function (or any function that takes a *float* and turns it into something else), you need to specify the parameter as a float, not a long.

Comment: return type in assignment is long...

Comment: Also, if you have a working `floor()`, its trivial to use that to create a `ceil()`, in most cases you'll just add 1 to the output of `floor()`.  In the rest, you'll add 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
long floor(double f)
{
    if( f >= 0.0 ) {
        return int(f);
    } else {
        return ( int(f) - 1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double floor(double d)
{
    if(d>0)return static_cast<double(static_cast<int>(d));
    return static_cast<double>(static_cast<int>(d-1));
}
```

This is one way to implement floor().

Comment: You'd probably want to return an integer type here

Comment: forgot to cast the return value there. almost.

Comment: I'd stay away from subtracting a constant because for large double values the mixture of precision would probably cause strange things to happen.